# Is it possible to make .gitignore configurable based on environment variables?

Tags: linux, git, gitignore, gitattributes

Is it possible to add to .gitignore rules depends on environment variables?

for example

```
if -e $(ENV_VAR) "AAA"
!liba.so
else
liba.so
```

---

Basically what I want is to have a repository such that `if ENV_VAR = "AAA"` the local repository will have `a.txt` and if `ENV_VAR` isn't set the a.txt will be removed.

Comment: Skimming [the git docs for gitignore](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitignore.html), the short answer is probably No.

Comment: Why do you want to set up a gitignore file this way, what is the problem you're trying to solve? Maybe there's a better solution.

Comment: This would definitely be improved by more context.

Comment: I want to have a repository such that if ENV_VAR = "AAA" the local repository will have a.txt and if ENV_VAR isn't set the a.txt will be removed.

Comment: you can easily have different .gitignores in different branches. on one branch you either use the file from the repo or you do not use the file, so i do not see how a change of the environment would affect this.

Comment: The reason I'd want to do it is so I can avoid accidentally checking in changes that I've made just so I can debug my code. Let's say I make a temporary change to a file so I can debug something, but I never want to check that temp change in. I'd like to temporarily add that file to .gitignore for my command line session, but I don't want to accidentally check in my change to .gitignore either. Having the ability to `export GITIGNORE=path/to/that/file` would be helpful in this circumstance.

Comment: @JohnnyLambada, can you please make your comment as an answer? I think that it's a good proposal.

Comment: Hi @0x90, I've added an answer.

Comment: @JohnnyLambada, I can't see it... I can see only your commenty

Comment: @0x90 since it was not an answer, someone deleted it.

Comment: @JohnnyLambada, no one here delete answers, please package it into an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: 0x90 It's not true that no one deletes answers -- @kjhughes did just that. I undeleted it and modified it slightly so that it actually answers the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>Currently the answer is no</strike> Yes, but not using an environment variable.

My use case is simple; I'd like to avoid accidentally checking in changes that I've made to a specific file so I can run my code locally.

Let's say I add my super secret password to the `src/assets/secrets.xml` file so that I can run my code locally, but I never want my password to leak to github so it can be found with tools like [this](https://github.com/michenriksen/gitrob).

Originally I thought having the ability to `export GITIGNORE=path/to/that/file` would be helpful in this circumstance.

But since that's not an option, here's how to accomplish the same goal.

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged src/assets/secrets.xml
```

To undo this effect:

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged src/assets/secrets.xml
```

After re-reading the OP's question a couple of times, I'm not sure if this will do what he's asking.

Comment: @kjhughes I changed my answer to actually answer the question, then modified the rest of my answer to provide a use case where it would be helpful as the OP requested

Answer (score 5):

The answer is no.
Gitignore rules are static. You can turn around it by dynamically creating your .gitignore file. So, you will also have dynamically created static rules.

This can be easily done within the application building system such a Makefile. The .gitignore file can rebuilt each time the project is built.

Example Makefile:

```
all: my_app .gitignore

.gitignore: some deps
    cp my_static_gitignore_rules .gitignore
    echo 'dynamically_created_rule1' >> .gitignore
    echo 'dynamically_created_rule2' >> .gitignore

my_app: my_app.c
    ...
```

Comment: It's not a standard way to do it, but very smart and nice.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is no.

Gitignore rules are completely static. Further that would not even make any sense. Once a file is in the repo, gitignore does not apply to it anymore – it only prevents **new** files from being added.

That being said, you can have a local “gitignore”: anything in `.git/info/exclude` will also be ignored. Within the limits I just explained.

Answer (score 0):

Here there is a nice workaround
https://gist.github.com/wizioo/c89847c7894ede628071

by wizioo
Julien LIBERT