# Can I use macros/variables in a `.gitignore` script?

Tags: bash, git, variables, macros, gitignore

Is there any way to use macros or variables (à la `bash`) in a `.gitignore` script? The [gitignore docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) don't mention anything along those lines, but I figured I'd ask just in case there's some undocumented features and/or cool workarounds. A few people [have](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17640160/425458) [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26670878/425458) about using environment variables in a `.gitignore`, but I want to know if there's any support whatsoever for macro-like or var-like anything.

### use case

I have a repository which has been undergoing a refactoring of its directory structure/paths. Certain paths are used in multiple patterns in my `.gitignore` script, so it would be nice to be able to have something in there along the lines of:

```
# set a variable
UNSTABLE_PATH=foo/bar

# use the variable in some patterns
$UNSTABLE_PATH/test_data
$UNSTABLE_PATH/test_output
```

And yes, before you say it, I'm aware that clever use of glob and/or recursive glob could probably cover my use case. It would just be nice if there was some simple variable support as well. Though come to think of it I would also settle for a way to make the `git mv` command rewrite matching paths in the `.gitignore`.

Comment: I certainly hope not. I don't want `.gitignore` files to be potentially Turing complete. That would open up whole new attack surface.

Comment: Also, why do you call them "scripts"? AFAIK, they are not intended to ever be executable.

Comment: @sampablokuper I feel you. I have to interact with `LaTeX` on a regular basis, which is at its core a (with-some-qualifications) turing complete hairball/gordian knot of macros

Comment: @sampablokuper Also, a `.gitignore` isn't plain text and it isn't source code so... script? ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ What do you call them?

Comment: `.gitignore` files are plain text configuration files. "Scripts" are also plain text files, but are written in [scripting languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scripting_language), and are executable (either by being marked as executable in the file system and having a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)), or by being run as an argument to the scripting language interpreter). Some configuration files are also scripts (e.g. `~/.bashrc`) but some are not (e.g. `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` and, I *hope*, `.gitignore`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'll just jump to the end of the semantics debate in the comments and leave it at this:

`.gitignore` is not a script, it's a list of patterns.  As you would then expect, it has no support for variables.

If you really need this ability, I would take a cue from the likes of sass or less:  Write your own file of "ignore rules with extended syntax" and write a script to boil that down into a proper `.gitignore` file.

But if you want my two cents, this looks like another case that would be resolved by moving some stuff outside your work tree, so that the work tree can just be a work tree.